# Laravel send email on form submit

Tags: php, laravel

So I have a simple form and I want whenever a user submits the form it to email me, not sure what the problem is as whenever I submit the form I'm getting a 500 error and I'm not sure why.

Here is the form:

```
<div class="contact" id="contact">
    <form action="{{url('/contact')}}" method="post">
        {{ csrf_field() }}
        <input type="text" class="fname" name="firstname" placeholder="First Name">
        <input type="text" class="lname" name="lastname" placeholder="Last Name">
        <input type="text" class="address" name="address" placeholder="Address">
        <input type="text" class="email" name="email" placeholder="Email">
        <textarea id="subject" name="message" placeholder="Message" style="height:200px"></textarea>
        <label class="checkbox-label">
            <input type="checkbox" class="yard" name="yard"> I Want a Yard Sign
        </label>
        <br>
        <label class="checkbox-label">
            <input type="checkbox" class="host" name="host"> Host a Meet and Greet
        </label>
        <br>

        <input type="submit" value="Get More Information">
        <br>
    </form>
</div>
```

And in my web routes file I have my two routes setup

```
Route::get('/contact', function () {
    return view('contact');
});

Route::post('/contact', function (Request $request) {
    Mail::send(new ContactMail($request));
    return redirect('/');
});
```

I created my Mail file

```
<?php

namespace App\Mail;

use Illuminate\Bus\Queueable;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Queue\ShouldQueue;
use Illuminate\Mail\Mailable;
use Illuminate\Queue\SerializesModels;

class ContactMail extends Mailable
{
    use Queueable, SerializesModels;

    public $email;

    /**
     * Create a new message instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->email = $request;
    }

    /**
     * Build the message.
     *
     * @return $this
     */
    public function build()
    {
        return $this->subject('New Contact Mail')
                    ->from($this->email->email, $this->email->firstname)
                    ->to('test@gmail.com')
                    ->view('email.contactmail');
    }
}
```

And then my simple blade file

```
{{ $email->content }}
```

Whenever I submit the form or try and call the route I get a 500 error and I'm not sure why.

Comment: In your `ContactMail` class constructor, you're assigning an undefined variable `$request`.

Comment: And you should really turn on error reporting in development. That way you'll get meaningful errors, instead of the generic error 500 meant for the users.

Comment: Yeah so I forgot to add use Illuminate\Http\Request; but Im still getting the same error

Comment: That's not your problem. Your problem is you didn't define the constructor to take a parameter.

Comment: For future reference, the full details of the problem will be in your Laravel, PHP, and/or web server logs. You are developing blind if you're not using them.

Comment: what does the error say in the file `laravel.log`?

Answer (score 0):

I think you forgot to insert `Request $request` as a parameter on the class constructor and import the Request class.

```
<?php

namespace App\Mail;

use Illuminate\Bus\Queueable;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Queue\ShouldQueue;
use Illuminate\Mail\Mailable;
use Illuminate\Queue\SerializesModels;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class ContactMail extends Mailable
{
    use Queueable, SerializesModels;

    public $email;

    /**
     * Create a new message instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct(Request $request)
    {
        $this->email = $request;
    }

    /**
     * Build the message.
     *
     * @return $this
     */
    public function build()
    {
        return $this->subject('New Contact Mail')
                    ->from($this->email->email, $this->email->firstname)
                    ->to('test@gmail.com')
                    ->view('email.contactmail');
    }
}
```

Also, as per your description, you may not have debug on. Change it at .env file:
APP_DEBUG=TRUE

Comment: Ok, yeah I fixed that but still same 500 error, let me turn on the debug to see what it spits out, hmm it is already turned on or set to true

Comment: Ok! Do it and let me know :)